# помогите подобрать плагин для слайдера

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перерыл кучу плагинов, не могу нормально реализовать. Скорей всего у меня просто руки такие кривые, может кто то поможет ? по клике на миниатюру она отображается в увеличенном виде. а так же миниатюрки прокручиваются вертикальным слайдером, а при адаптиве он превращается в горизонтальный

Comment: fotorama пробовали? Покажите хоть один вариант. что и как запускали. настраивали.

Comment: У фоторамы нет возможности отобразить превью слева,  пробывал слик но при установке в две колонки он 2 превью считает за одно.

Comment: @ЕвгенийБондаренко, данный ресурс предназначен для вопросов, связанных с программированием - но не для поиска компонентов и/или библиотек. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте ваш вопрос, чтобы он соответствовал формату данного сайта - либо, обратитесь на другой, более подходящий для подобных вопросов (например, на "Ответы мэйл.ру").

Comment: Насколько помню, плагин Master Slider имеет возможность располагать иконки маленьких фото как горизонтально, так и вертикально. Только стоит искать и пробовать версию Master Slider jQuery, так как в основном этот плагин для вордпресса. Вот только не уверен, что иконки можно располагать в два ряда.